# Class initialization breaking application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I've recently created a new class for my iPhone application which will hold information read from a text file containing the street address and GPS points of points of interest.

The issue though is that whenever I add code to initialize the class my application loads up and the instantly quits with no errors in the console. When I remove it, everything is fine. I simply cannot see anything wrong with the code.

Here is the constructor:

```
#import "GPSCoordinate.h"


@implementation GPSCoordinate
-(GPSCoordinate*) initWithData:(NSString *)rawData size:(int)size
{
self = [super init];
location = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size];
coordinates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(int)size];

NSArray *tokens = [rawData componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    //Sub tokens
    NSString *line = [tokens objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *lineTokens = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    //Store address
    [location addObject:[lineTokens objectAtIndex:0]];
    //Store GPS coords
    NSString *coords = [lineTokens objectAtIndex:1];
    coords = [[coords stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""] 
              stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([coords length]-2, 1) withString:@""];
    NSArray *coordsTokens = [coords componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = [[coordsTokens objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    coord.longitude =[[coordsTokens objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    [coordinates addObject:coords];
    [line release];
    [lineTokens release];
    [coords release];
    [coordsTokens release];
}

return self;
}

@end
```

Here is the call I make to it in another class:

```
self.gps = [[GPSCoordinate alloc] initWithData:gpsRawData size:[[gpsRawData componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count]];
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Is there any crash message on console?

Comment: there is no error checking on any of the paramaters, I would start there.

Comment: Have you but a break point in there?  Might get you to the individual line.  You can get information about the objects at the console by typing `po <object name>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a number of problems.

- You're not checking the return value of [super init].
- You're storing autoreleased arrays in what are presumably ivars (location and coordinates).
- You're passing a separate size parameter which is calculated from the rawData outside of the call, but -initWithData: makes the exact same calculation inside the method. The size: parameter seems completely superfluous here.
- You're skipping the last token entirely. You should take that for loop and make the condition simply `i < size`. Alternately if you're targetting iOS 4.0 or above you can turn the entire loop into

  ```
  [tokens enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
      NSString *line = obj;
      // rest of loop body
  }];
  ```

  Since you don't seem to need the index inside the loop, you could also just use a for-in loop (this will work on pre-4.0 iOS devices):

  ```
  for (NSString *line in tokens) {
      // body of loop
  }
  ```
- You're not checking that your data is valid. If a line contains "foo", your program will crash when it tries to access `[lineTokens objectAtIndex:1]`. Similarly it'll crash if you have the string "foo:" as it tries to remove the first character of the `coordinates` variable. In fact anything less than 2 characters after the colon will crash. It'll also crash if there's no spaces after the colon.
- And finally, all those calls to `-release` at the end will crash. All 4 of those objects are autoreleased objects, so by calling `-release` on them now you're simply guaranteeing that the app will crash when the autorelease pool is drained.
- You're also storing `coords` (e.g. the string) in your `coordinates` array. Presumably you meant to store `coord`, though you'll need to wrap it in an NSValue in order to store it in an NSArray.

Comment: +1 for the for-in suggestion; I think that would help this code a lot

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues.

1) Most fundamentally, you are releasing a lot of objects that you didn't allocate. For example:

```
NSString *line = [tokens objectAtIndex:i];
....
[line release];
```

is incorrect. Review the [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

2) Why are you doing `[[gpsRawData componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count` to pass the size to 
your `initWithData:size:` method, when you're just going to have to repeat the `-componentsSeparatedByString:` call inside your method. Passing a separate "size" doesn't gain you anything, involves a redundant parse of the input, and opens up more possible bugs (what if the caller passes in a "size" that doesn't match the number of "@"s in the input - you aren't handling that error condition).

3) I also see that you are assigning latitude/longitude to `CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;` but not doing anything with it. Is that deliberate?